# Parser for MIME type "text/html" in RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

i'm using RestKit (v0.20.3) and when i obtain a response to a GET HTTP request, i cannot parse it because I get this error:

```
Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) 
with content type 'text/html' UserInfo=0x6c4a2b0 
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://helloEverybody.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x6c4a1e0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"
```

Here is my code:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];

NSURL *baseUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://helloEverybody.com"];
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
[objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"user" password:@"password"];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/html"];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"It worked!!: %@", [mappingResult firstObject]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"It failed: %@", error);
}];
```

I've read a lot of similar post, and they usually fix this issue changing the server response to json, but i can't touch the server. I need to parse these "text/html".

Anyone know how can i do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is the response really valid JSON.